# How to adjust the height of NavigationButtonBar in WizardForm

Tags: c#, windows, wizard

How to adjust the height of NavigationButtonBar in Microsoft.WizardFramework.WizardForm ? It's locked? Can I modify the attribute of the _buttonbar?

Thanks

Dma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use reflection in C# to get the _buttonBar and modify the attribute.

Thanks
Dma